# How to find and delete nodes with duplicate titles?

Tags: nodes, feeds

I used [Feeds](http://www.drupal.org/project/feeds), and for some reason it imported several nodes multiple times; now I have many duplicates.

How could I easily find and delete such nodes?

Comment: I have the same problem, why feed import multiple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Drupal 6 script](http://drupal.org/node/720190) should do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQL request:

```sql
SELECT nid, title, type 
FROM node 
WHERE title IN (
    SELECT title FROM node
    GROUP BY title HAVING count(*) > 1)
ORDER BY title, created DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this.**

```
    $nids = db_query("SELECT nid FROM node 
    WHERE  type=:type 
    GROUP BY title HAVING count(*) > 1", 
    array(':type'=>'node_type'))->fetchAllKeyed(0,0);

   //Now delete all the duplicate nodes.
    node_delete_multiple($nids);
```